# How does Haskell 'read' infer types

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference

I learned before that when using Haskell's `read` function when reading numbers from `String`s you need to specify the type of output, as:

```
read "2" :: Int
```

unless you do something like:

```
read "2" + 2
```

Haskell then knows you're trying to do addition, hence it must be a number.

However, one particular function caught my attention, because by looking at function i thought it would not compile, but it does, i don't know why.

This reverse polish notation calculator that implements addition, subtraction and multiplication:

```
solveRPN :: (Num a, Read a) => String -> a  
solveRPN xs = head . foldl foldingFunction [] . words $ xs
    where   foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "*" = (x * y):ys  
            foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "+" = (x + y):ys  
            foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "-" = (y - x):ys  
            foldingFunction xs numberString = read numberString:xs
```

if you give it a string like "2 5 +" it will return 7.

last line of this code is what i can't understand. When you give this function "2 5 +" the first element in `xs` list will be "2" and accumulator at time is `[]`, hence it will slip through first 3 patterns and last one will do its job, hence:

```
 foldingFunction [] "2" = read "2":[]
```

So, my question is: How come `read "2":[]` dosen't crash? If I tried to execute this bit in console it would give parse error becasue `read` wouldn't know what that string should be, right? how come it's not `(read "2" :: Int):[]` or something?

Comment: See my answer for an explanation as to why `read 2` gives a `Parse error` in ghci.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you have to understand is that Haskell assigns all the types of functions at compile time, not run time. Also, that functions have only one type for all their patterns.

What this means is that it will decide that the type of the function is overall and use that decision in every case. Also, Haskell does rather heavy type inference (unlike most other languages), and so will sometimes determine the type of a function based on the type of something that might seem a bit far away from the original function call.

Let's look at your example:

```
solveRPN :: (Num a, Read a) => String -> a  
solveRPN xs = head . foldl foldingFunction [] . words $ xs
    where   foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "*" = (x * y):ys  
            foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "+" = (x + y):ys  
            foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "-" = (y - x):ys  
            foldingFunction xs numberString = read numberString:xs
```

First off, the type of `solveRPN` is declared as `String -> a`.

Now, looking at the definition of `solveRPN`, we have the first line saying:

```
solveRPN xs = head . foldl foldingFunction [] . words $ xs
```

Now, the types of the names used there are:

```
xs :: String    (from the type of solveRPN)
head :: [b] -> b    (I'm using different variable names for each different type)
foldl :: (c -> d -> c) -> c -> [d] -> c
words :: String -> [String]
```

So the type of `solveRPN` means that we must have that type `b` is the same as type `a`, and since `head` is applied to the output of `foldl`, we must have that type `c` is the same as type `[a]`. Now since the third argument to `foldl` is of type `[String]`, we know that type `d` is `String`, and now we have enough to determine the type of `foldingFunction`:

```
foldingFunction :: [a] -> String -> [a]
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's work backwards.

1. `head . foldl foldingFunction [] . words :: Num a => String -> a`
2. `foldl foldingFunction [] .words :: Num a => String -> [a]`
3. `foldl foldingFunction [] :: Num a => [String] -> [a]`:

Since `foldl ::Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`, we can see that `t a ~ [String]`, so we can also see that `foldingFunction :: Num a => [a] -> String -> [a]`.

Thus, `read "2" : [] :: Num a => [a]`, the same type as `foldingFunction [] "2"`.

In other words, `solveRPN` provides the necessary context to infer what `read` should return.

Comment: I'd like to know what ghci is trying to do when you type `read "2"` at the REPL prompt.

Comment: `read "2" :: Read a => a`. There is no default type for `Read a => a`, producing a parse error.

Comment: Normally if GHC doesn't know which instance you are referring to is says "There are several potential instances ..." and then list out the instances available. In this case it is actually proceeding with the `read` with some type in mind. But which type? For instance, evaling `read undefined` results in the undefined error - so some type's read function is actually looking at the string.

Comment: haskell is so mind-boggling and awesome at the same time. Thanks! By the way, i can even omit function type, haskell figures it out anyway. Amazing

Comment: @ErikR I think the difference may have to do with whether the function is polymophic in an *argument* (e.g., `show`) or in its *return value* (as is the case with `read`). A problem with an argument is caught immediately; a problem with the return type is deferred until it is actually evaluated.

Comment: But - what code is emitting `Parse error`? GHCI is clearly finding some function to run - so what function is being run, and what rules did GHCI use to find that function?

Comment: `read` is. But at the prompt, with no further context, `read` doesn't know what to actually return, so *it* raises the error. `read` *always* takes a `String` as its argument, so dispatch is not a problem. Once `read` *starts* to run, and can't figure out what to do with its argument, the exception is raised.

Comment: Well  - I got this one explained - I posted it as a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

> If I tried to execute this bit in console it would give parse error becasue read wouldn't know what that string should be, right?

(Thanks to [haskell-cafe mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haskell-cafe/juEd1ZJizUE) for help on this.)

You are getting a parse error at the GHCI REPL because in the absence of a type context, GHCi evaluates the expression as if it were the type `()` (the empty tuple type.)

For instance, this does not give an error:

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> read "()"
()
```

This is a consequence of the `-XExtendedDefaultRules` option which is implicitly in effect when using GHCi. See [Type defaulting in GHCi](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci) in the [GHC User Guide](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/index.html) for more details on why GHCi has these extended defaulting rules.

To see how this option affects evaluation, you can perform the same experiment with the option disabled:

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :set -XNoExtendedDefaultRules
Prelude> read "2"

<interactive>:3:1:
    No instance for (Read a0) arising from a use of ‘it’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    ...
```

Now we get a `No instance for ...` error message. This is the message that tells you that GHC does not know which type to return.

Answer (score 0):

The context `(Num a, Read a) =>` on your `solveRPN` function are enough for `read` to figure it out.  Try this in ghci:

```
let n = read "2" :: (Num a, Read a) => a
:t n
```